# Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio in mixed logistic model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, optimization, biostatistics, convergence

I am investigating effect of various "treatments" on various disease outcomes with univariate mixed logistic regression models corrected for covariates:

```r
f1 <- as.formula(paste(disease, "~ age + ", t, 
        "+ (1 | relatives)"))
```

where

`disease` is binary
`age` is continuous
`t` is binary
`relatives` is a factor (relatives have the same factor number)

The code for the model is:

```r
glmer(f1, data = data, family = binomial, 
    control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",   
    optCtrl=list( maxfun=2e5 )))
```

For some of the `diseases`/`treatment` combinations, I get the warning:

```r
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, 
  ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue   
  ratio
```

(and sometimes other convergence warnings).

I don't think scaling age (my only continuous variable) would be of use.

I've checked `table(disease, t)` and sorted `data` according to `age` and looked at `disease` but do not see perfect separation problems.

Sometimes I notice correlation (>0.75) between `(Intr)` (intercept?) and some of the variables in the `summary` under `Correlation of Fixed Effects:` but then on other occasions, I have convergence warnings with the correlations around 0.

Other things I've tried:

- Increasing tolerance
- Different optimizers
- Restarting from a previous fit

as recommended [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/33653_57fc7b8e5d484c909b615d8633c01d51.html). None of these worked.

I'm not comfortable with ignoring the warning for these instances as some of the coefficients, standard errors, and p-values are wild, making me distrust the results.

I am thinking my only option might be to exclude combinations for which this is a problem but I think this doesn't really solve the problem and may lead to loss of information.

Am I missing something?

What could be causing these problems despite having an apparently simple model?

Comment: Not sure causes the problems without knowing more about the data (I'm guessing the issue is quasi-complete separation), but possible solutions may include likelihood ratio tests (less sensitive to such issues than Wald) or stabilizing the parameters via weakly informative priors such as [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/ecostats_chap.html#digression-complete-separation).

Comment: How big of a dataset are we talking here?

Comment: @PBulls agreed that it seems that way I exclude instances for which there are too few observations in a straticiation of the data (e.g., if the number with both `t` and `disease` is less than 10% they are eliminated. @user11852 I have about 16 000 variables being tested against 40 diseases, and sample size per variable/disease combination but is around 90 usually